# Extract images urls from markdown content

Tags: c#

I have markdown content which contains images like:

```
#this is markdown content

![image alt text](https://via.placeholder.com/200)

Remaining content ...
```

Using C# I need to get the urls of all images in the markdown content.

In previous content I would get `https://via.placeholder.com/200`.

I am getting matches of `![image alt text](https://via.placeholder.com/200)` using:

```
var matches = new Regex(@"!\[.*?\]\(.*?\)")
                .Matches(content).Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => m.Value)
                .ToList();
```

But I am not sure how to get the urls of images ...

Comment: Just use capturing group, something like `!\[.*?\]\((?<url>.*?)\)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by user @Evk you can capture the url in a group. The code to access the url without a named group would be:

```
var matches = new Regex(@"!\[.*?\]\((.*?)\)")
   .Matches(text);

if (!matches.Any())
    return;

var url = matches[0].Groups[1].Value;
```

and with a named Group:

```
var matches = new Regex(@"!\[.*?\]\((?<url>.*?)\)")
   .Matches(text);

if (!matches.Any())
    return;

var url = matches[0].Groups["url"].Value;
```